# Как в JS вставить разметку HTML?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет.

Подскажите, как в JS вставить HTML блок с содержимым?

Например:

```
<div class="ds">Текст текст</div><div class="sdf12">Текст текст</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var as='<div class="ds">Текст текст</div><div class="sdf12">Текст текст</div>';

</script>
```

Так оно почему-то не работает, а как правильно, чтобы потом подключил этот файл и оно читало разметку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aqjLk2yk/

http://jquery-docs.ru/attributes/html/

http://jquery-docs.ru/attributes/text/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqjLk2yk/1/ можно ещё один вариант, пригодится

Answer (score 3):

Надо значение этой переменной `as` как-то вставить в нужном месте документа. Например, если там есть пустой `<div>` с известным  `id`, то можно так ([пример 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/nktf3jae/)):

```
document.getElementById("mesto").innerHTML = as;
```

Или можно, например, в конец документа, или известного элемента, добавить свежесозданный `<div>` с вашим html ([пример 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/nktf3jae/1/)):

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.innerHTML = as;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
```

**jQuery облегчает** эту же задачу. Те же два способа будут выглядеть по одной строке:

```
$("#mesto").html(as); // в элемент с id="mesto"
// или
$("body").append(as); // в конец документа, не оборачивая в доп. div
```

---

**Если HTML много**, в несколько строк, можно его обернуть в отдельный тег с id:

```
<script id="html-1" type="text/template">   // заметьте, что это НЕ javascript!
    <div class="ds">Текст текст</div>
    <div class="sdf12">Текст текст</div>
</script>

<script> // а это уже нормальный JavaScript
    var as = document.getElementById("html-1").innerHTML;
    // или то же с jQuery:
    var as = $("html-1").html();
    // а далее как всегда : )
    // ...
</script>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо, все заработало. )) ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="ds">Текст текст</div><div id="sdf12">Текст текст</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ds").innerHTML    = "Текст текст";
    document.getElementById("sdf12").innerHTML = "Текст текст";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ставим вот такие кавычки `` (<kbd>Ё</kbd> клавиша), допустим

```js
var htmlText = `<div class="ds">Текст текст</div>
<div class="sdf12">Текст текст</div>`
```

выводим:

```js
document.write(htmlText)
```